# What other phrases derive from specific famous crimes, true or fictitious?

Tags: phrases

I don’t know what made this enter my mind, but I found it very interesting that the following phrase is so commonplace but comes from a very recent crime:

> #### drink the Kool-Aid
>
> : to demonstrate unquestioning obedience or loyalty to someone or something.
>
> Alludes to the Jonestown Massacre, the mass murder of 909 people in 1978.

I started racking my brain for other examples, and was able to come up with a decent one:

> #### gaslight
>
> : to attempt to make (someone) believe that he or she is going insane (as by subjecting that person to a series of experiences that have no rational explanation).
>
> Alludes to British play *Gas Light* (1938) in which Jack attempts to convince Bella that she is going crazy in order to hide the fact that he is attempting to steal his neighbour’s jewellery and ultimate that he murdered the neighbour.

Granted, the second example isn’t perfect because *gaslight* alludes to the psychological manipulation, not the murder, but it’s alright in my book because I’d consider it a form of witness tampering!

**What other phrases in English have their etymologies in famous, specific crimes?** The crimes can be true or fictitious, and they don’t have to be murder.

Comment: Whoever voted to close this question as having “multiple questions in one”: please show me where the second question is.

Comment: True, only one question, but it’s off-topic to ask for a list. Nevertheless, I’ve provided an answer. I find the idea interesting, and I doubt there are very many such phrases.

Comment: @Xanne If it’s off-topic to ask for a list then why do we have the  [tag:list-request] tag? That’s bogus.

Comment: It isn't a phrase, but _burking_ (named after William Burke), referred originally to a method of smothering victims (in order to sell their cadavers for medical research). As I recall, Boris Karloff has a memorable line in one of his films—perhaps _The Body Snatcher_ (1945)—when he turns to a companion and says "Would you like to see how I burke them?"  _Bluebeard_, as a name for a man who kills his wives one after another, derives from a fairy tale character named "Bluebeard." A _quisling_ (named after Vidkun Quisling) is a politically powerful or influential person who commits treason.

Comment: @SvenYargs That’s perfect! I would definitely upvote all of those! Please considering reposting that as an answer....

Comment: “This tag exists solely to indicate that these questions are off-topic”. It seems weird that we have a list request tag but it’s clear from its description that it’s off topic.

Comment: Are you prepared to adhere to site regulations now that it has been pointed out that requests for lists (other than synonyms so that the best fit may be assessed) **are** off-topic? This _is_ an interesting question, but belongs on a different website. If this is allowed, next we get 'words of nine letters beginning with _t_ that are a type of sausage'. I'd try Literature.SE.

Answer (score 1):

**Ponzi scheme**

> In the 1920's, Charles Ponzi carried out this scheme and became well known throughout the United States because of the huge amount of money that he took in.[5] His original scheme was based on the legitimate arbitrage of international reply coupons for postage stamps, but he soon began diverting new investors' money to make payments to earlier investors and to himself.[6] Unlike earlier, similar schemes, Ponzi's gained considerable press coverage both within the United States and internationally both while it was being perpetrated and after it collapsed – this notoriety eventually led to the type of scheme being named after him.[7]

Comment: I think that this is closer to a strict legal term that was named after someone than a “phrase” in the sense I intend. If we accept this term, then we would also need to accept *Miranda rights*, *AMBER Alert*, etc., and that’s really not what I’m going for.

Comment: I’m downvoting for the reason I explained above.

Comment: You have asked for phrases describing famous crimes. You have invited the entire law library so stand back.

Comment: Ponzi scheme is a strict legal term?

Comment: @gen-zreadytoperish - I've heard the term *Ponzi scheme* used many times in contexts outside of the legal system. It's definitely used with broader meaning than terms like *Miranda Rights*. I've heard it used metaphorically. It may not be what you *wanted*, but it does seem to fit pretty nicely within what you *asked for*, so it seems a bit harsh to then vote the answer down.

Comment: @nnnnnn Hmm . . . perhaps you’re right, and now I’m inclined to agree with you. Unfortunately I can’t retract my vote.

Answer (score 0):

**the dog that didn’t bark**

The phrase identifies something that is significant because it didn’t happen.

From a Sherlock Holmes story:

> [. . . which] features some of Conan Doyle's most effective plotting, hingeing on the "curious incident of the dog in the night-time":

> Gregory (Scotland Yard detective): Is there any other point to which you would wish to draw my attention?

> Holmes: To the curious incident of the dog in the night-time.

> Gregory: The dog did nothing in the night-time.

> Holmes: That was the curious incident.

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Adventure_of_Silver_Blaze

See [https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?corpus=26&smoothing=3&content=dog+that+didn’t+bark&year_end=2019&year_start=1800&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdog%20that%20did%20not%20bark%3B%2Cc0](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?corpus=26&smoothing=3&content=dog+that+didn%E2%80%99t+bark&year_end=2019&year_start=1800&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdog%20that%20did%20not%20bark%3B%2Cc0) for examples in both fiction and non-fiction.

Comment: Do you have any evidence of *the dog that didn’t bark* being used as a stand-alone phrase rather than a quote from Sherlock Holmes? I could not find any source that uses it without having to explain the allusion along with the usage.

Comment: I’m downvoting for the reason I explained above.

Comment: The fictitious incidents are notable for their presence whether they occurred in the story or not. That is the nature of language, not just English. Also points for mentioning Doyle.

Comment: I could search for it, but I’ll let you do that part. I have seen the phrase used in articles and non-fiction books.

Comment: https://www.thenational.ae/business/the-curious-case-of-the-dog-that-did-not-bark-1.485803#:~:text=The%20non%2Dbarking%20dog%20refers,wish%20to%20draw%20my%20attention%3F%22 The expression is fairly well-known, especially since the publication of the novel _The curious incident of the dog in the night-time_.